# Could not find Id of Hidden Text in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

This is my aspx page

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="PrintColumn" DataField="PrintColumn" HeaderText=""
    HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblIDSIDPrint" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DSID") %>'/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="lblDataDSPrint" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DataDS")%>'/>
        <asp:LinkButton Style="text-align: right; float: right;" ID="lbDSPrint" runat="server"
            OnClientClick="popWin">Print</asp:LinkButton>                                                     
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

This is my javascript

```
function popWin() {
    var Dsid = document.getElementById('<%=lblIDSIDPrint.ClientID %>').value;
    var DataDs = document.getElementById('<%=lblDataDSPrint.ClientID %>').value;
    alert(Dsid);
    alert(DataDs);
}
```

But I am getting an error

> "CS0103: The name 'lblIDSIDPrint' does not exist in the current context"

Any suggestions on this.

Comment: try :- `var Dsid = document.getElementById('lblIDSIDPrint').value; alert(Dsid);`

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: One more thing. If I click on any value on grid view only the first value is shown in the alert am i doing any mistake? thanks

Comment: if you want to show multiple value then use class selector. try to read javascript class seletor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
var Dsid = document.getElementById('lblIDSIDPrint').value; alert(Dsid);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `$(document).find("#lblIDSIDPrint").val();`